# "Symbol" brand barcode scanner and c#

Tags: c#

I have a "Symbol" brand barcode scanner (USB) and I am trying to capture the data it scans from a barcode into my application (which is running as a service -- with no textbox control, of course).

The catch is that : Whenever you scan something, it acts like a keyboard and outputs the digits to anything that has focus (i.e notepad, word, etc).

My question is: How do I perform this barcode scan in the background and put it in a variable that I can use in my in C#.

So far, the only api's that I've found are for the .NET CF and I need this to be a 
windows service.

---

Basically, I want to be able to send certain keystrokes to an application if the barcode = "123456789-0111" without interfering with the current window that has focus. After my application reads the barcode in then it will look for a certain program (launch it and set focus) and send keystrokes. I am using Code 128.

Comment: Can you give us more information on the context of why it **has to be a windows service**?

Comment: I was thinking it would have to be a windows service because I need to be able to monitor the data coming from the barcode scanner *all* the time. Basically, I want to be able to send certain keystrokes to an application if the barcode = "123456789-0111" for example.

Comment: It could also be in the system tray.

Answer (score 2):

The HID mode will be your best best.

Put the barcode reader in HID mode and make your service capture the reader. When data comes in take a look at it and if it is one of your special barcodes you can act on it.

If the data is not one of your special barcodes then inject them as keydown/keyup windows messages so that it will seem to work in the same fashion as in keyboard emulation mode.

Comment: +1 if you explain HID mode.  I did a quick Google but came up with stuff around bluetooth.  Does it stand for "human interface device"?

Comment: This is exactly how I deal with it in one of my commecial apps.
The handheld scanner will appear as it's own HID, so you just hook into it's keystrokes via windows API and monitor away!

Answer (score 2):

1. Put the scanner into USB mode. This is generally done by scanning a series of barcodes in your manual or printed out from the software provided from symbol.
2. With the scanner plugged in/docked connect to windows update. You'll get an update specific to that scanner. It won't work if if the scanner is not plugged in.
3. The scanner should map to a com port. This has typically been com 2 on the machines I've set it up on.
4. Download [JustinIO](http://www.aciss.com/justin/io.htm). For my scanner, useful COM settings: Baud Rate: 9600, ByteSize 8, StopBits: 1 Parity: 0
5. Create a new CommPort instance. Set up a thread that does something like:

---

```
StringBuilder sb;
byte[] b;
do
{
    b = commPort.Read(1);
    sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(b));
    Thread.Sleep(20); //symbol is slow... 
} while(b.Length > 0);
```

Note: that's much crunched down from the code that I'm actually using so you'll need to modify it for your application.

6. Send the string to your application via whatever method seems appropriate.

Comment: Weird. I tried to format it for you, but I can't get it to work either. Must have to do with being part of a numbered list.

Answer (score 0):

The scanner is configured as HID (human interface device) and emulating keyboard.
To access it through Symbol's API, you probably have to disactivate current communication mode and set it to native one - should be documented in the scanner manual. Then you can access it directly without input field.

PS. I have no Symbol's scanner, but this is common to many devices.

Comment: The only problem with this approach is that they use the same scanners to scan in other barcodes, so it has to be set to active communications mode at all times.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends upon the barcode scanner's api, and that is specific to the vendor. You'll need to get the the api for the scanner from the vendor, if you can't find it on their site you should just email their support, though you might find you have to buy the api.

Comment: So far the only api that they have is for the CF.

Answer (score 0):

First..

Ignore the .NET CF info for now as it probably pertains to the actual handheld unit.   The mode of operation, pretending to be a keyboard, is referred to classically as a 'keyboard wedge'.

Second..

What kind of barcode symbologies are you attempting to use? And for what purposes? Or, mor directly,...What do the barcodes look like when scanned? (Do they contain special leading and trailing characters?)

Third... keep it simple... avoid the API unless it is necessary...

In the past when I've had to interface with barcode scanners, I've used a very simple approach in that my data entry form has the property of KeyPreview true and contains a method to detect and direct input originating from the scanner (by examining starting and trailing characters) to the appropriate control.   Most of the scanners I've dealt with were programmable (usually via barcodes)  to pass a custom set of characters to signal beginning and end of scanned input.

I hope that helps....

Comment: 1) Code 128
2) purpose is for a hospital to quickly navigate through certain screens. 
3) It is up to me if I want them to contain special leading and trailing characters. Each clinic will be assigned a barcode that I come up with.

Comment: Looks like your program does data entry based on some paper form or label. Probably Lab or charges.  I suspect the approach detailed above will likely work.

Comment: The only problem with your approach is that my form is running in the background and does not have focus. The user will be in another application when they scan the barcode. If the user was in my application, then I could use the KeyPreview on the form, regardless of which control has focus.

Comment: I've dealt with a similar problem but the target computer had a dedicated function and the application was always in the foreground.

You describe the occasional use of the barcode scanner and you'd prefer the scanner to trigger the proper application focus along with the data.

That is sufficient reason to run a background service.  TWK's suggestion is probably the correct one.

Symbol *may* have already an OS utility to launch or direct input to certain programs.

I'm curious.. is this a simple 'dumb' scanner?  or is it one of the models running an accessible embedded os? (such as WinCE..)

Comment: It is a simple 'dumb' scanner. I can't remember the model number, but it is programmable using a barcode in the instruction manual.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a CodeProject sample that demonstrates how to set up global mouse and keyboard hooks in C#:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/globalhook.aspx

You could add this code to your console application, and then just monitor all keyboard input, looking for the specific codes you need.  No API fuss or muss.