# Get the MAC Address of BARCODE SCanner

Tags: c#

I've got this USB barcode scanner, Im able to read the barcode on and its fine.

Ive a requirement where in Multiple scanners (let us say 5-6)are configured on a single device and I need to get the configured Scanner's Mac Addrress,Based on the Mac address certain operations need to be performed. All i need is how to get the scanners Mac Address.

This is the first time i'm working with the Barcode.

I have tried this:

```
static List<USBDeviceInfo> GetUSBDevices()
        {
            List<USBDeviceInfo> devices = new List<USBDeviceInfo>();

            ManagementObjectCollection collection;
            using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"Select * From Win32_PnPEntity"))
                collection = searcher.Get();

            foreach (var device in collection)
            {
                devices.Add(new USBDeviceInfo((string)device.GetPropertyValue("DeviceID"),(string)device.GetPropertyValue("PNPDeviceID"),
                    (string)device.GetPropertyValue("Description")));
            }
            collection.Dispose();
            return devices;
        }





class USBDeviceInfo
    {
        public USBDeviceInfo(string deviceID, string pnpDeviceID, string description)
        {
            this.DeviceID = deviceID;
            this.PnpDeviceID = pnpDeviceID;
            this.Description = description;
        }
        public string DeviceID { get; private set; }
        public string PnpDeviceID { get; private set; }
        public string Description { get; private set; }
    }
```

Comment: Are they working in USB [mode](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1336332/529282)?

Comment: Yes.Model is  Code Soft cs3260  Wireless Barcode Scanner.

Comment: Can anyone help me??

Comment: Have you tried the step mentioned in the answer I [linked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314774/symbol-brand-barcode-scanner-and-c-sharp/1336332#1336332)?